# Spring Message Converter for xml and json

Tags: java, json, xml, spring, jaxb

Can someone please help clarify and show how to properly go about this issue?

What I understand so far is that the Spring framework uses Message Converters when a method is annotated with `@ResponseBody` to convert the return Java object to a format that can be accepted by the Client. If the clients' HTTP request Accept Header includes "application/json", it will use Jackson and the Jackson converter to convert the object and return it in a json format. Similarly if the Accept Header includes "application/xml", then the Message Converter will use Jaxb and the corresponding converter to convert the object to xml.

Now my issue is that I include both the Jackson and Jaxb libraries as specified in Spring documentation so that the corresponding converters can work. This should be enough for Spring to employ `@ResponseBody` as its supposed to. However, when I send an HTTP Request with the Accept header "application/xml" I get a 406 status code and when I send one with "application/json" I receive a correct json response.

From my research online, I see that some people use the ContentNegotiation technique to work around this, but I would like to use the Message Converter for now. However, every technique to make the Message Converter technique to respond to json and xml resource requests involve formatting my POJO with JAXB annotation. Is this really necessary?

I guess what I am asking is how would one set up their project properly so that Spring can use the Message Converter technique to respond to json and xml requests? What libraries must be included? Does one need to add JAXB annotations or is there an automatic way for Spring to format an object into xml the way it does for json?

I thank you for your time and help with this, but so far I am really loving Spring's implementation of JAX-RS!

Comment: If that works depends a little on the return type/value of your controller. It has to be a top level entity annotated with the proper JAXB annotations else it won't do anything.

Comment: @Hector Sanabria you need to add jaxb annotations in your model then only the xml conversion will work. The jaxb and jackson have different way of mapping and structuring elements.